# Get current conversation/channel id in Slack Api

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to create global shortcut that displays a modal. In it I need to have a channel select field as I will later post a message to it, and I wish to have the opened channel as the default option.
I see in the [docs](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/shortcuts/using) that only message shortcuts get a channel_id on the body, but I know that apps like [simple poll](https://light-it.slack.com/apps/A0HFW7MR6-simple-poll?tab=more_info) manage to achieve this so there must be some kind of workaround.
[simple poll modal that default to opened channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVMsD.png)

I can't seem to find any conversation_id in the payload I am getting for the global shortcut, and can't seem to find a way to filter the conversations API to retrieve the one I am focusing on